# Why my tornado application always re-authenticates?

Tags: python, authentication, tornado

I am building a web application based on Python tornado and I am struggling with the authentication process. Based on the demos provided with tornado I create an authentication through Google.

- I authenticated and get redirected to my index.
- I try to connect to my `/profile` site, but tornado redirects me to Google Authentication and to my index.

`/profile` requires that the user is authenticated. In my case, tornado doesn't seem to
accept it or I made a mistake in the Authentication classes.

**Why I cannot access my `/profile` site? What I am doing wrong with the authentication?**

**Authentication related handlers**

```
from site import models

import mongoengine

import tornado.auth
import tornado.escape
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

from tornado import gen

class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get_current_user(self):

        user_json = self.get_secure_cookie("mysite")
        if not user_json: return None
        return tornado.escape.json_decode(user_json)


class AuthGoogleLoginHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.GoogleMixin):

    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):

        if self.get_argument("openid.mode", None):
            user = yield self.get_authenticated_user()
            self.set_secure_cookie("mysite",
                                   tornado.escape.json_encode(user))

            email = user.get('email')

            try:
                print 'trying to find the user'
                usr = models.User.objects.get(email=email)

            except mongoengine.DoesNotExist as e:

                # there is no user with the wished email address
                # let's create a new one.
                new_user = models.User()
                new_user.email = user.get('email')
                new_user.first_name = user.get('first_name')
                new_user.last_name = user.get('last_name')
                new_user.locale = user.get('locale')

                new_user.save()

            self.redirect('/')
            return

        self.authenticate_redirect()


class AuthLogoutHandler(BaseHandler):
    '''
    Log the current user out.
    '''

    def get(self):
        self.clear_cookie("mysite")
        self.redirect('/')
```

**Other handlers and main**

```
from mysite import models

from mysite import auth

from tornado.options import options, define, parse_command_line
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.escape
import tornado.wsgi
import os

define('port', type=int, default=1234)

class ProfileHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def get(self):

        join = lambda x, y, separator: separator.join([x, y])
        self.render('profile.html', user=user, join=join)


class ProfileEditHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def get(self):    
        self.render('profile-edit.html', user=user)

    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def post(self):

        first_name = self.get_argument('first_name')
        last_name = self.get_argument('last_name')

        city = self.get_argument('city')
        state = self.get_argument('state')
        country = self.get_argument('country')

        # write to MongoDB
        self.redirect('/profile')

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('welcome.html')    

def main():

    template_path=os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),"templates")
    static_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'static')

    wsgi_app = tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler())

    handlers = [('/profile', ProfileHandler),
                ('/profile-edit', ProfileEditHandler),
                ('/auth/login', auth.AuthGoogleLoginHandler),
                ('/auth/logout', auth.AuthLogoutHandler),
                ('/', IndexHandler),
                ('.*', tornado.web.FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=wsgi_app)),]

    tornado_app = tornado.web.Application(handlers,
                                          static_path=static_path,
                                          template_path=template_path,
                                          cookie_secret='some_secret',
                                          login_url='/auth/login',
                                          debug=True)

    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(tornado_app)
    server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. When the `get` method of my `ProfileHandler` was called the `@tornado.web.authenticated` decorator checks if a user is logged in.

But who finds out if there is a logged in user or not? In the basic tornado functionality this is not implemented. You have to create a `BaseHandler` and all other handlers which
need this authentication information should subclass the `BaseHandler`.

After the `BaseHandler` was defined and subclassed - authentication worked perfectly!

To sum it up. If you get stuck in a vicious cycle of log in requests:

**1) Create a `BaseHandler` and override `get_current_user`.**

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get_current_user(self):

        user_json = self.get_secure_cookie("heroe")
        if not user_json: return None
        return tornado.escape.json_decode(user_json)
```

**2) Subclass BaseHandler with your common handler:**

```
class ProfileHandler(BaseHandler)
```

**3) Add the tornado decorator `@tornado.web.authenticated` to ensure authentication:**

```
class ProfileHandler(auth.BaseHandler):

    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def get(self):
        self.render('profile.html')
```